# CordovaPush plugin always returning OK on register

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-build, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm following those docs:

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

I am trying to follow the Android example, and when I try to register, no matter what my senderId is, I am always getting the OK result.

When I instert the actual GCM sender ID, I still get OK instead of a registration ID. I did all the setup, Googled and tried all solutions, still couldn't make it work.

I really need to get this working, but I can't find the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following for Push Notification in Android and iOS. It will work properly for you. After install the app, user will need to open the app for call ecb methods. In iOS, PushNotifcation's register success method will returns the mobile register id in result but in android, it will return only OK. In Android, onNotificationGCM method will be called for two type event 1) RegisterId and 2) Notification Message. I have also added the showNotificationAPN/GCM method for show notification popups with $ionicPopup.alert().

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, PushProcessingService) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        try {
            PushProcessingService.initialize();
        } catch (e) {
            //hide event
        }
    })
})

.factory('PushProcessingService', ["$window", "$ionicPopup", function ($window, $ionicPopup) {
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            pushNotification.register(gcmSuccessHandler, gcmErrorHandler, {'senderID': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'ecb': 'onNotificationGCM'});
        } else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            var config = {
                "badge": "true",
                "sound": "true",
                "alert": "true",
                "ecb": "pushCallbacks.onNotificationAPN"
            };
            pushNotification.register(gcmSuccessHandler, gcmErrorHandler, config);
        }

        var addCallback = function addCallback(key, callback){
            if(window.pushCallbacks == undefined){
                window.pushCallbacks = {};
            }
            window.pushCallbacks[key] = callback({registered:true});
        }
    }

    function gcmSuccessHandler(result) {
        console.log("Register push notification successfully : " + result);
        if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            var mobileType = "ios";
            var mobileRegisterId = result;
            // Save the ios mobile register Id in your server database
            // call the following method on callback of save
                addCallback("onNotificationAPN", onNotificationAPN);            
        }
    }

    function gcmErrorHandler(error) {
        console.log("Error while register push notification : " + error);
    }

    return {
        initialize: function () {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
        },
        registerID: function (id) {
            var mobileType = "android";
            // Save the android mobile register Id in your server database
            console.log("RegisterId saved successfully.");
        },
        showNotificationGCM: function (event) {
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: "Pajhwok Notification",
                subTitle: event.payload.type,
                template: event.payload.message
            });
        },
        showNotificationAPN: function (event) {
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: event.messageFrom + "..",
                subTitle: event.alert,
                template: event.body
            });
        }
    }
}])

onNotificationAPN = function(event) {
    if (!event.registered) {
        var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]'));
        var injector = elem.injector();
        var myService = injector.get('PushProcessingService');
        myService.showNotificationAPN(event);
    } else {
        console.log("Registered successfully notification..");
    }
}

function onNotificationGCM(e) {
    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
            {
                // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]'));
                var injector = elem.injector();
                var myService = injector.get('PushProcessingService');
                myService.registerID(e.regid);
            }
            break;

        case 'message':
            // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
            // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
            var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]'));
            var injector = elem.injector();
            var myService = injector.get('PushProcessingService');
            myService.showNotificationGCM(e);
            break;

        case 'error':
            alert('<li>ERROR :' + e.msg + '</li>');
            break;

        default:
            alert('<li>Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is.</li>');
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: best solution I have found on the internet by far!

Comment: @rodlin : Thanks Dear :)

Comment: It is working fine for me. Thanks for the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that moving over my code from module.run to a controller did the trick.

Exact same code, I guess it's something to do with the scope? Who knows. And I'm sure the code on module.run was being executed (I had a lot of logs there). Go figure.